# Increasing minSdkVersion causes Out Of Memory errors

Tags: android, android-manifest

I developed my app with minSdkVersion set to 3, targetSdkVersion set to 8.

My app is published, and runs on everything from Android 1.5 to 3.0 *Though devices it will run on with anything older than 2.0 is always spotty, some it will and some it won't*

It works perfect on my Incredible, Android 2.2. It uses 5-8mb memory when running.

However I decided I wanted to split it into two different apps, one for Android 1.5 and 1.6 compatibility and another with higher quality images optimized for tablets.

The only line I changed was setting minSdkVersion from 3 to 5, and all of a sudden it won't run on any phone or emulator?
Now on my Incredible, it uses 7mb just to show the menu background, and gives me an out of memory error every time when loading another image.

Any ideas? Thanks

```
04-25 17:19:45.476: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(20145): 7094850-byte external allocation too large for this process.
04-25 17:19:45.476: ERROR/dalvikvm(20145): Out of memory: Heap Size=4871KB, Allocated=2517KB, Bitmap Size=19170KB
04-25 17:19:45.476: ERROR/GraphicsJNI(20145): VM won't let us allocate 7094850 bytes
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.ht/com.ht.Garage}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.ht.Panel
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3347)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3362)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.ht.Panel
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1654)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at com.ht.Garage.onResume(Garage.java:165)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1255)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3864)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3337)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     ... 12 more
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at com.ht.Panel.<init>(Panel.java:107)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     ... 23 more
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:574)
04-25 17:19:45.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20145):     ... 27 more
04-25 17:19:48.066: ERROR/ActivityManager(97): fail to set top app changed!
```

Comment: Check your error message and post it here.

Comment: If you change it back to 3 does it work?

Comment: Yes if I change it back to 3 it works again.

Comment: Would it be a permission that API 3 has by default but I'll have to request with a higher API version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to fix it, setting anyDensity to false works. I don't understand why it works though.

With API 3, anyDensity has a default value of false, but I was setting it to true!

With an API of 4 (or is it 5) or higher, anyDensity has a default value of true.

How is it any different between it defaulting to true with API 7, and me setting it to true with API 3?

That should not affect memory usage at all, it ends up being the same value no matter what!

Oh well, my app hasn't needed anyDensity set to true since I put in code to dynamically scale the images based on screen size and density anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Set your minSdkVersion to API level 7, API level 5 and 6 are no longer available as 2.0 has been completely phased out.  The Android SDK manager does not offer those API's any longer as an available package because they have been marked as obsolete.  I just did a new install on a new system and found the API's unavailable.

Comment: This did not work, I still recieve exactly the same error. Only thing that works is setting it back to 3